# CORS enabled using Express but still getting CORS error

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using React and Express. Here is my code in Express.

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const { connection } = require("./db/connection")
const user = require("./routes/user")
const product = require("./routes/product")
const rentalHistory = require("./routes/rental-history")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/upload"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Carbon Copies Rest Api" })
})

app.use("/user", user)
app.use("/product", product)
app.use("/rental-history", rentalHistory)

module.exports = { app }
```

When I hit this link https://carbon-copies-restapi.herokuapp.com/image_1628058210309.jpeg on the frontend. It throws this CORS Error. Other routes work just fine

[image]

Comment: try putting the `app.use(cors())` right after `const app = express()` - I think your static paths do not have CORS enabled because you are declaring it before adding the `cors` middleware.

Comment: Already tried that but it didn't work

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/104) you should use it like this: `app.use(cors)`, although you did it exactly like in the documentation, so I'm not sure which one's right

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i solved adding 'origin: true' in the cors configuration.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}))
```